# Python converting string to UTF

Tags: python-3.x, pysnmp

I have an OctetString value `0xe4c722d60a61` (it's a MAC address, actually) that my code is nerfing to UTF on conversion to a string e.g. `'äÇ"Ö\na'`.

The code processes a lot of data and only a small subset is of this type.

How can I stop this from happening?

This is the output:

```
(Pdb) snmpVal
[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(<ObjectName value object at 0x7f77d152eef0 tagSet <TagSet object at 0x7f77d620ba20 tags 0:0:6> payload [1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.3]>), <PhysAddress value object at 0x7f77d152e7b8 encoding iso-8859-1 subtypeSpec <ConstraintsIntersection object at 0x7f77d61d7518 consts <ValueSizeConstraint object at 0x7f77d61d74e0 consts 0, 65535>> tagSet <TagSet object at 0x7f77d620b550 tags 0:0:4> payload [e4:c7:22:d6:0a:60]>)]
(Pdb) snmpVal[0][1]
<PhysAddress value object at 0x7f77d152e7b8 encoding iso-8859-1 subtypeSpec <ConstraintsIntersection object at 0x7f77d61d7518 consts <ValueSizeConstraint object at 0x7f77d61d74e0 consts 0, 65535>> tagSet <TagSet object at 0x7f77d620b550 tags 0:0:4> payload [e4:c7:22:d6:0a:60]>
(Pdb) str(snmpVal[0][1])
'äÇ"Ö\n`'
(Pdb) hex(snmpVal[0][1])
*** TypeError: 'PhysAddress' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is the code:

```
    cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, snmpVal = cmdGen.getCmd(
        cmdgen.UsmUserData(user, 
                        authKey=authKey, 
                        privKey=privKey, 
                        authProtocol=authProto, 
                        privProtocol=privProto, 
                        securityEngineId=None
                ),
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((sHost, 161)),
        '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.3' )
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear on what you are looking for. Can you post the code that is actually producing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to deal with raw OCTET STRING value, just call `.asOctets()` on the object. You will end up with `bytes` (Py3) or `str` (Py2). From here you could run unicode decoder if you need to turn OCTET STRING into unicode (which I doubt is a good idea).

If you want human-friendly representation of the MAC address, just call `.prettyPrint()` on the object. If it has been already resolved against a MIB, then pysnmp knows that it's a `PhysAddress` kind of `OctetString` so `.prettyPrint()` will turn it into colon-separated hex form.

Comment: Thanks Ilya! Does the pysnmp project take donations? I think I owe you a coffee!

Comment: @fileinster Most certainly! Let's have a coffee someday! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to convert that to a UTF string by the sounds of your description. Python has a built-in function called `hex` that you can use. It converts any `int` value into a hex string. From there you can just add the colons yourself with some list comprehension and string joining. Try this:

```
a = hex(0xe4c722d60a61)
print(':'.join(a+b for a,b in zip(a[::2],a[1::2]))[3:])
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a string to start with; more detail added to explain better.